# VBA Excel to PDF not working in loop

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to create a macro that will identify and PDF individual banker's portfolio. The macro will filter on the banker's name (showing only their portfolio) and will PDF and with banker's name in the PDF file. The macro runs without any error. It is able to identify the banker, adds to a collection, and filters through all the bankers. However, it doesn't PDF anything. I haven't been able to identify the issue. Please help!

My code:

```
Sub CreatePDFs()
'
' CreatePDFs Macro
'

' Identify distinct banker names in Column E and store in a collection
Dim BankerCollection As Collection

Dim Banker As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set Rng = Range("E5", Range("E5").End(xlDown))
Set BankerCollection = New Collection

On Error Resume Next
For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
BankerCollection.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
Next Cell

' Loop through each banker name in the collection

For Each Banker In BankerCollection

' Copy each banker name to cell B1
Range("B1").Value = Banker
Range("B1").Font.Bold = True

' filter on the banker name, and PDF with banker name in document title
Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Banker, VisibleDropDown:=False

ThisFile = Banker + " Portfolio"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisFile, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Next Banker

End Sub
```

Comment: "The macro runs without any error."  How can you tell that it had no errors when you are masking errors with the `On Error Resume Next` statement?  Comment that line out and see whether an error occurs.

Comment: Could you comment all the other lines except the Activesheet.ExportAs and try to zero in the error.

Comment: Do you see the PDFs open as you create them? Perhaps you are not finding the PDF files in the correct folder after they have been created.

Comment: No, I don't see the PDF. I don't think they were created. I checked in the default folders and no files were created.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line of your code

```
 ThisFile = Banker + " Portfolio"
```

with this

```
 ThisFile = Banker & " Portfolio"
```

> P.S It turns out you don't have to make this change your code runs fine without the change.

Comment: DV for two reasons. 1) User has no such line of code in the question. 2) The line `ThisFile = Banker + " Portfolio"` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks for correction. I got that wrong, when I ran it for the first time it gave me error on that line.

Comment: Dim ThisFile as String at top? Runs if i add that in

Comment: This may indeed fix the problem **if** the OP has numeric values in column E.  (That would lead to `Banker` being a `Variant/Double`, which will then cause VBA to get upset when it tries to do an addition such as `12345 + " Portfolio"`.)  But the question implies that it is the banker's **name** that is in column E rather than, perhaps, their ID number.

Comment: @LearningVBA Does that mean that the bankers' names were actually numbers?

Comment: @YowE3K Banker names are text, not ID.

Comment: @LearningVBA "Thank you QHarr! That works!!" If it works (and I can't see how it can if the banker names are text) you should "accept" this answer by clicking on the "tick" to the left of the answer.